# Check how many weeks have past

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a program that will check to see how many weeks have passed from a certain day. I am using JQuery and JavaScript this code somewhat works in the sense that it does give a result that I want but the results skip 4 weeks at a time

for example ***it goes from #Tip0 to #Tip4***

how would I fix this

```
var today = new Date();
var date_start = new Date('2014-07-19'); //date to check from
var timeinmilisec = today.getTime() - date_start.getTime(); //check time past
var weeks = Math.floor(timeinmilisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 7 ; // calculate weeks
    setInterval(      //update every 100 miliSec
        function () {
                for( i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    if (i < weeks ) {
                        i--;
                        $("#Tip" + i).hide()
                        i++;
                        $("#Tip" + i).show()
                    }
                }
            },
     100);
```

Comment: on a side note, try timeAgo jquery plugin.

Comment: why would you need to run this 10 times a second when the timeframe you are checking against is in weeks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a construct needs a closure. And you do not want to change `i` within the loop.

```
var today = new Date();
var date_start = new Date('2014-07-19'); //date to check from
var timeinmilisec = today.getTime() - date_start.getTime(); //check time past
var weeks = Math.floor(timeinmilisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 7 ; // calculate weeks
    setInterval(      //update every 100 miliSec
        function () {
                for( i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                    (function( i ) {  //Closure START
                        if (i < weeks ) {
                            $("#Tip" + (i - 1)).hide()
                            $("#Tip" + i).show()
                        }
                    })( i );          //Closure END
                }
            },
     100);
```

Comment: I tried this but I was still having the the same issue with skipping but thank you for the information, I am still learning.

Comment: Please create a demo so we can have a better view of the issue.